# Android - Change position of android action bar

Tags: android, android-animation, android-actionbar

I am trying to build a **slide out menu like Facebook and Path apps**. I want to place a button on right end of action bar which would trigger opening and closing the menu. When the menu would slide in to make itself visible I want to slide out the main view towards left along with the action bar.

Everything else works fine. I am using the open source code available at - https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo

But I am not able to find out if I can apply **slide animation to the action bar too**? If not, designing my own action bar and including in activity layouts is the way to go I believe.
I would appreciate any expert guidance in this matter.

Comment: You may have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11367825/361413.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, this isn't possible.  The ActionBar object doesn't inherit from View, so you can't get any of the layout parameters.  I believe that it actually resides outside of the window that gets supplied to your activity.  So for the effect you're describing, a custom action bar might be in order.  Alternatively, you might consider have a transparent/ translucent action bar overlaying your activity, that you show/hide when that panel pops out (as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Removing)) - just a thought, but ultimately do what you feel offers the best UX for your application.

Comment: Thanks JRaymond. That was really helpful. I am still waiting to hear from more people.